# taking 3 and 4 days off current date not working

Tags: php, date, strtotime

It is as simple as this really, I'm messing around with a few things and currently its to do with the date... so I have this...

```
$day = date('d',strtotime("+0 days"));
$month = date('M',strtotime("+0 days"));
$year = date('Y',strtotime("+0 days"));
$date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;

$echo $date;
```

and there is no problem with this. But messing around with it trying to add/takeaway days from it, that is when I get a problem. When Ii do this..

```
$day = date('d',strtotime("+1 days"));
$month = date('M',strtotime("+1 days"));
$year = date('Y',strtotime("+1 days"));
$date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;
```

again I get know problem and I can add how every many days, there's never an issue, when I take away days though, I can take 1,2,5,6,7,8,9 and so on.. days away but trying to take 3 or 4 days away, like ...

```
$day = date('d',strtotime("-3 days"));
$month = date('M',strtotime("-3 days"));
$year = date('Y',strtotime("-3 days"));
$date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;
```

it doesn't take that amount of days away, it just takes 1 away from the current date. Can anyone explain why this is happening? and why I cant get just take 3 & 4 days off the current date?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://eval.in/101874

Comment: what's your problem, exactly? Please provide sample data. I don't understand what is it that you're having problems with.

Comment: i know that it should work fine, and there is nothing to provide, im on a blank page messing around with a different things trying to learn new stuff, im messing around with what i put above and for some reason when I, and only when I -(minus) 3 or 4 days it just doesnt work, it only takes just just the 1 date away

Comment: and the problem im having is im just trying to figure out why taking these away just are not working and was hoping someone could maybe point out why, thats all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$now = date("d/M/Y");
$newDate = date("d/M/Y", strtotime('-3 day'.$now));
```

You can do all stuff in above one line instead of getting days, months separately.

Comment: i know it can be done in one line and I've tried it the way you have said, its separate as i did something recently where i put the date into  the database separately, days, month, year in individual fields. thats the only reason why they are separate, i was trying to split the date so i "could" enter them separately into a database

Comment: Okay. But you shouldn't. Save full date and use `strtotime` to get days or months.

Comment: i know that now, just at the time i did and i just thought see if i could figure a few issues out i was having with it, then this thing started playing up, when i use the full date, it takes 3 & 4 days off, it just when i use the single 'd' it doesnt seem to want to work

Comment: What about this?
`$now = date("d");
$day = date("d", strtotime('-3 day'.$now));`